# What is the equivalent of SENTRY_USER_ATTRS in the new SDK sentry-sdk/sentry-python?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, sentry, flask-security

How do you configure the user data sent when using `send_default_pii=True` with flask-login for the Sentry Unified Python SDK?

The docs say:

> If you use flask-login and have set send_default_pii=True in your call
>   to init, user data (current user id, email address, username) is
>   attached to the event.

However, doing so only passes along the id and email. How can I configure more attributes to be sent?

In the previous version of the SDK (raven-python), this could be configured with SENTRY_USER_ATTRS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `before_send`:

```
def before_send(event, hint):
    try:
        user = flask_login.current_user
        user_info = event.setdefault("user", {})
        user_info["myattribute"] = user.myattribute
    except Exception:
        pass
    return event


init(..., before_send=before_send)
```

More info: https://docs.sentry.io/learn/filtering/?platform=python#before-send